# Print the environment variables WITHOUT VALUES in C

Tags: c

How to print the environment variables in C, but WITHOUT VALUES ?? Only variables.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    while(*envp!=NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", *envp);
        envp++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just strip out the values, e.g. with `strtok`, using `=` as a delimiter?

Comment: Note you shouldn't be messing around with the *original* environment you get through `getenv` , especially not with stuff like `strtok`, that *will change the environment of the process*. Work on a copy, or use less-intrusive methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since environmental variables have format of `NAME=value` you need to display only part of string up to `=` character.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    while(*envp!=NULL) {
        char * len = strchr(*envp, '=');

        if (len == NULL)
            printf("%s\n", *envp);
        else
            printf("%.*s\n", len - *envp, *envp);

        envp++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/Uy3R4Y)

Comment: No problem. If my answer help you, then select it as answer, or upvote.

Comment: Is `ptrdiff_t` a valid type for the `*` in the format string? I would imagine that it expects `int` or `size_t`.

Comment: To be honest, i don't know - according to [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), it required `int`.

Comment: Yes, the standard requires an `int`, so the pointer difference needs to be converted to `int`. It's probably reasonably safe to assume the length of the environment variable name will fit in an `int`, so a simple cast should do.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are of the form `NAME=value`. So, you can look for the first `=` sign and print only upto it to get only the names.

Comment: You can do the search (and print) in many ways. Here's one: http://ideone.com/LedegN